# Log history of rails commands run on a given project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does anybody know of a way to record all the rails commands that have been run into a log file?

Spring Roo does this, which allows you to 'replay' those commands in a different project.

It would also be really handy to be able to see the code involved, plus rails commands that were executed for a given source control commit.

Thanks

Comment: It probably wouldn't be all that hard to monkey patch both rails and rake to accomplish what you need, but I'll wait for others to answer if they know of a better approach.

Comment: http://rors.org/2011/07/17/inline-logging-in-rails-console